# reference error in ASP.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net5

I play around with some commands like dnvm and dnu, and now when I create an empty ASP.NET 5 solution, I get reference error like this:

```
Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS >= 1.0.0-beta5 could not be resolved
Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener >= 1.0.0-beta5 could not be resolved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Core beta 8, these two references have changed.

- `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS` has been replaced by `Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler`
- `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener` has been replaced by `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`

And RC1 is available now. ;)

Comment: thanks for the tip.
I install ASP.NET 5 RC and everything works fine.